# Yahoo Mail SMTP Android

Tags: android, yahoo-mail

Following this thread : [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap) , I've tried to send a mail from a yahoo account using smtp.mail.yahoo.com and 465 as a port. The mail is sent but no sender is attached to the mail. If I send from a gmail account the user address is attached..

Any help will be aprecieted!

Comment: Fount the answer! In the example was message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender)); and I've changed it to message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender)); !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fount the answer! In the example was

```
message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
```

and I've changed it to

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender)); !
```